# Use quantiﬁers to express:"There is someone who loves no one besides himself or herself"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

If $L(x,y)$: x loves y.

Use quantiﬁers to express:

"There is someone who loves no one besides himself or herself"

The answer given by textbook is $∃x∀y(L(x,y) ↔ x=y)$

But I think $∃x∀y(L(x,y) → x=y)$ is also correct, right?

Comment: no, thats wrong as your expression does not say that $x$ loves himself, even though the difference is subtle I have to admit.

Comment: so,how about this ∃x∀y(L(x,y) ∧ x=y)?

Comment: On a possibly amusing side note, the logician Quine used to put this question on exams for introductory courses:  "As the song goes, 'Everybody loves my baby, but my baby don't love nobody but me.'  Prove that I am my baby."

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1488516/11994

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you interpret the English sentence "There is someone who loves no one besides himself or herself". Does the sentence imply that this someone loves himself/herself? If no, your answer is correct; if yes, the textbook's answer is correct.

Comment: how about this ∃x∀y(L(x,y) ∧ x=y), assume that he loves himself.

Comment: @Ned: That sentence says in effect that there is exactly one person, and that person loves himself.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of ↔

Comment: @NedStack: Then you've identified your problem. **Understand** exactly what the primitive boolean operations mean, via their truth tables. Only **after that** then try to figure out how to translate English sentences to logical language.